# Can I have HMR (hot module replacement) with Routify?

Tags: javascript, svelte, hot-module-replacement, routify

How can I use [Svelte HMR](https://github.com/rixo/svelte-hmr) with [Routify](https://routify.dev/), notably in the [Routify starter](https://github.com/sveltech/routify-starter), that has a somewhat special Rollup config?